# Intellectual property in the Age of Industry 4.0

Tags: contract-law, intellectual-property, patents

I am looking for specific references describing guidance principles around the interplay between IP (intellectual property) and Artificial Intelligence algorithms. For example, Company A has a large dataset and Company B has advanced algorithmic capabilities (assume near-AI). How might Company A protect itself in a joint partnership with company B? Apologies if this SE is not the place for this - any suggestions for the right site?

Comment: Sounds like you are mostly interested in patent or copyright law; plus, the answer involves contracts. Billions of pages have been written on those topics, so you need to be more specific.

Comment: As @user6726 says -  a well thought out, mutually agreed to, contract is the answer. I ran a small company who had a joint development agreement with a giant player and the contract negotiations took almost as long as the R&D did.

Comment: @user6726 - agreed, but as I am not a legal expert (a technologist, rather), I am looking for case studies, examples, literature to guide my thinking.

Comment: this is one such example https://www.ictsd.org/sites/default/files/research/ceipi-ictsd_issue_5_final_0.pdf. But when dealing with algorithms and data it seems very hard to distinguish where one ends and the other begins - especially in the context of training algorithm models.

Comment: As a start, you could explain what you think makes it hard to distinguish the two (*I* don't have any problem distinguishing the two). Maybe your real question is something like "how does copyright law distinguish data *qua* facts and a program?".

Comment: A contract that says we will share all revenue from our collaborative work on an X:Y percent basis, as a starting point.